# How to get the child n of current element?

Tags: jquery

I have a page similar to the structure below:

```
<div id="row_2">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

How do I get the nth child of row_2, assuming that I cannot use that id (e.g. I'm on row_1 and I'm moving to the next one)

I have tried the following:

```
current.parent().next().children().filter(":nth-child("+i+")");
```

where "current" is an item on the previous "row div" and "i" is an index for an item, but this doesn't work. I also tried using 0 in place of "i" to test it, but that doesn't work either - where's the error?

Comment: thanks to all for the answers - changing from nth-child to eq made it work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you are looking for [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/),  not `nth-child`:

```
current.parent().next().children().eq(i);
```

As the docs state for `eq`:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but I'd suggest:

```
current.parent().next().find(":nth-child("+i+")");
```

Or:

```
current.parent().next().children().eq(i);
```

If you have a need to use `filter()`, I'd suggest (though without knowing exactly what's going on) maybe trying:

```
current.parent().next().children().filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).is(":nth-child("+i+")");
    });
```

But I can't see the advantage, unless you wanted to filter for other criteria as well.

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 1):

#### If your starting point is `row_1`, then:

```
var row2child3 = row1.next().children().eq(2); // zero-based index, 2 = third child
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/umapiz) | [source](http://jsbin.com/umapiz/edit)

That assumes that `row_1` and `row_2` are immediately adjacent, e.g.:

```
<div id="row_1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div id="row_2">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

If not, you might want `.nextAll("some selector here").first()` rather than `.next()`.

#### If your starting point is one of the *items* in `row_1`, then:

..insert a `parent()` in there:

```
var row2child3 = item.parent().next().children().eq(2); // zero-based index, 2 = third child
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/umapiz/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/umapiz/2/edit)